# how can I interrupt/stop animation when I rotate?

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, rotation

For example, I use the animation in landscape status, duration is 5.0s, from status A to B; in the middle of the 5.0s, I may rotate the iPad from landscape to portrait. I want the animation stopped and make the UI status to C after I rotated.

I'm not sure my question is clear.
How can I do that?

my animation code:

```
- (void)moveImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration x:(NSNumber*)dx y:(NSNumber*)dy
{

    // Setup the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // The transform matrix
    float fx = [dx floatValue];
    float fy = [dy floatValue];

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(fx, fy);
    //CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.4);
    //CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);

    image.transform = transform;

    // Commit the changes
    [UIView commitAnimations];    
}
```

Comment: I edited your question to remove the tag & word Xcode, as your problem has nothing to do with Xcode but with iOS.  Could you edit your own question again to add a little bit of code to show us how you are doing your animation?  There are a few ways to do animation, so any useful answer would depend on your implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **[Starting and Stopping Explicit Animations](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimatingLayers.html)** has a section on starting and stopping core animations
2. **[willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)** notifies you when the rotation begins.

So all have to do is 1) from 2)

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand.